# Is this right: “the whole France”?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adjectives, noun-phrases

I am not sure if this phrase is right: “for the whole France”. Here's the context:

> Sam applied these methods successfully at some sites in France and then was extended for the whole France by Nino.

Comment: Is *Nino* the successor to *Eighto* and the predecessor to *Tenno*, or do you mean *Niño*? :)

Answer (score 5):

The correct form is '**the whole of France**'. But it is not the only correction one could make to the sentence. It should read:

*Sam applied these methods successfully at some sites in France and then they were extended to the whole of France by Nino.*

Answer (score 4):

The sentence is wrong in a few aspects. The subject is Sam, but after the "and" it is no longer Sam, because Sam was not extended, or was he? Consider this as an alternative

> Sam applied these methods successfully at some sites in France and then they were extended for the whole of France by Nino.

Now the clause after the "and" has a new subject (they = the methods).

With regards to "whole" and "France", it should be "the whole of France".